# How do I fix SonarQube "variable is null on at least one execution path"?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nullreferenceexception

using sonarqube to analyze my code and being told "'alloc' is null on at least one execution path" for the following code

```
public RetirementAdvantageProgramSleeveAllocation(VariableDVAPolicy policy, Fund fund)
        : base(policy, fund)
    {
        SleeveAllocation alloc = null;
        if (fund.FundAccountType == FundAccountType.PortfolioChoice)
        {
            alloc = PortfolioChoiceAccountAllocation;
        }
        else if (fund.FundAccountType == FundAccountType.Heritage)
        {
            alloc = HeritageAccountAllocation;
        }
        else if (fund.FundAccountType == FundAccountType.RetirementProtection)
        {
            alloc = RetirementProtectionAccountAllocation;
        }
        alloc.PercentValue = fund.Value;
        alloc.PercentAllocation = fund.Value;
        alloc.Units = 0;
        alloc.Value = 0;
    }
```

`alloc.PercentValue = fund.Value;` is where i am getting the Possible System.NullReferenceException however is this a false positive? or do i really need to wrap all of these into a `if (alloc == null)`

thanks

Comment: You only assign value to `alloc` when some if is fulfilled. If none is fulfilled, the object will be null. Accessing `alloc.PercentValue` would generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three conditions - an `if` and two `else if`.

If any one of those conditions is met, `alloc` is assigned a reference.

But what if none of them are met? Then you're attempting to use `alloc`, but it's null.

The question is what should happen if none of those conditions are true. Do you want to throw an exception, or do you want to assign something else to `alloc`?

You could do that either in a final `else` :

```
else
    // throw an exception or assign something else
```

or you could add a check at the end:

```
if (alloc == null) 
    // throw an exception or assign something else
```

What you're doing might also be better represented as a `switch` statement, since all three conditions are checking the value of `fund.FundAccountType`. Technically it's going to do the same as what you're doing, but it makes it more readily apparent that all of the conditions are based on that one value.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check string is empty and null then you can use this
Styntx
**string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))**